# Where is a way to apply a filter in the overlayImage?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I would like to apply a filter in the overlayImage. the only way to do it, is appling the filter in the whole canvas after render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in support for this, but it's fairly easy to "hack".

```
var overlayImageUrl = '...';

// load overlay image first
fabric.Image.fromURL(overlayImageUrl, function(oImg) {

  // add and apply filter to overlay image 
  oImg.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale());
  oImg.applyFilters();

  // set <img> element of fabric.Image instance 
  // and assign it directly to canvas' "overlayImage"
  canvas.overlayImage = oImg.getElement();

  // render canvas for overlayImage to appear
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! it does the trick! 
Much better than my solution (put a new object with the filter on the top of stack and with PixelPerfect Detection).
Thanks again.